# Trying ot understand use of @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and @ContextConfiguration(locations= {/dao-context.xml})

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockito, spring-config, spring-junit

I am new to Spring and Junit testing. I am trying to understand use of  **@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)** and @**ContextConfiguration**(locations= {/dao-context.xml}) on line 1 and line 2nd below in my test. dao-context has datasource , entityManagerFactory and TranasctionManager beans defined.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) //Line 1
@ContextConfiguration(locations= {/dao-context.xml}) //Line2
Public class ProductServiceTest{

@Autowired
private void ProductDao productDao

......
.......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In order for the unit test to run a batch job, the framework must load
>   the job's ApplicationContext. Two annotations are used to trigger
>   this:
>
> `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`: Indicates that the class
>   should use Spring's JUnit facilities
>
> `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {...})`: Indicates which XML files
>   contain the ApplicationContext.

See more at [this official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/testing.html#creatingUnitTestClass).